# Add exponential curve to plot

Tags: r, plot, curve, exponential

I am looking to add a curve to my plot to show an exponential decrease over time. Ive plotted two small sets of data with the basic plot() function and just for clarity I wanted to add a smoothed line. 
The data points for the two datasets are

```
1.00000 0.37360 0.27688 0.22992 0.17512 0.13768 0.08048
1.00000000 0.44283122 0.30871143 0.23647913 0.22586207 0.09800363 0.06206897
```

with the x values showing the decay over time (0,1,2,3,4,5,6)

[image: plot]

Comment: Do you want to fit a specific model with exponential decay or just fit a non-parametric smoothed line? For the former, log your data and use `lm`, for the latter, try `loess`.

Comment: An specific model to show the exponential decay would be ideal

Comment: see `nls` in package `nlme` if you want to fit a model

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider providing a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to make it easier for us to help you. For example, you have provided two sets of y values (I think) but no x values. Please give some R commands we can copy-paste to reproduce your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use ggplot2 as it makes adding lines from fitted models so simple.

Without to much to go on the following may help you out....

```
#prepare the data
y <- c(1.00000, 0.37360, 0.27688, 0.22992, 0.17512, 0.13768, 0.08048,
   1.00000000, 0.44283122, 0.30871143, 0.23647913, 0.22586207, 0.09800363, 0.06206897)
x <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,0,1,2,3,4,5,6)
z <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)


dat <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y,z))

#load the library
library(ggplot2)

#plot the data
ggplot(data=dat,aes(x=x,y=y))+

#add Points with different shapes depending on factor z
geom_point(aes(shape=factor(z)))+

#Add line using non-linear regreassion
stat_smooth(method="nls",formula =  y~a*exp(-x*b),method.args=list(start=c(a=2,b=2)),se=F,color="red")+

#add line using linear regression
stat_smooth(method="lm",formula =  y~exp(-x),se=F,color="blue")
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks so much Micky. I'll definitely start using ggplot more now!

Comment: I'm glad it helped!